# Why am I getting SQL Error [1064] [42000] syntax Error

Tags: mysql, query

when running the below SQL Query i get the error message SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

```
select  (IFNULL(SUM(ls.principal_amount),0) - IFNULL(SUM(ls.principal_writtenoff_derived),0)
+ IFNULL(SUM(ls.interest_amount),0) - IFNULL(SUM(ls.interest_writtenoff_derived),0) 
- IFNULL(SUM(ls.interest_waived_derived),0)
+ IFNULL(SUM(ls.fee_charges_amount),0) - IFNULL(SUM(ls.fee_charges_writtenoff_derived),0) 
- IFNULL(SUM(ls.fee_charges_waived_derived),0)
+ IFNULL(SUM(ls.penalty_charges_amount),0) - IFNULL(SUM(ls.penalty_charges_writtenoff_derived),0) 
- IFNULL(SUM(ls.penalty_charges_waived_derived),0) ) AS "totalDue" from m_loan_repayment_schedule ls;
```

How can I resolve this error.

Comment: Probably not the cause. But shouldn't the ifnull be done before summing.  I  dont see tbe point of making null sum values 0.

Comment: @RohitGupta - I would expect to get the same answer either way.

Comment: Please show us the entire error message -- the "near" part of it gives a strong clue of _where_ the syntax error is.

Comment: SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 
- IFNULL(SUM(ls.interest_waived_derived),0)
+ IFNULL(SUM(ls.fee_charges_amo' at line 3

Comment: I tested your query (https://dbfiddle.uk/yMt3-UkM) but I get no syntax error. I think you have not posted the right query.

Comment: that is the error message I get when I tried running it on dbeaver community edition